# FIRST_VALUE in Athena or Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, amazon-athena, presto, trino

```
select id
      ,id2
      ,FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN app THEN date0 ELSE NULL END) IGNORE NULLS  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date0) as date_result
from (
select 1 id, 22 as id2, false app, Date'2019-03-13' as date0
union
select 1 id, 23 as id2, true app, Date'2019-03-14' as date0
union
select 1 id, 23 as id2, true app, Date'2019-03-15' as date0
)
```

Above query is returning like below in Athena

| id | id2 | date_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |  |
| 1 | 23 | 2019-03-14 |
| 1 | 23 | 2019-03-14 |

But I was expecting like below since we do ignore nulls and partition by id for date_result

| id | id2 | date_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 2019-03-14 |
| 1 | 23 | 2019-03-14 |
| 1 | 23 | 2019-03-14 |

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong in first_value? what is the best way to achieve this result in both Athena and spark? Thanks

I have added it in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong in first_value?

default frame for [windows functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) is unbounded preceding - current row:

> > If frame_end is not specified, a default value of CURRENT ROW is used.

> > If no frame is specified, a default frame of RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is used.

If you want to find value across the whole partition you need to specify the frame, for example:

```sql
with dataset(id, id2, app, date0) as (
    values (1, 22, false, Date'2019-03-13'),
    (1, 23, true ,Date'2019-03-14'),
    (1, 23, true ,Date'2019-03-15')
)

select id
     , id2
     , FIRST_VALUE(if(app, date0)) IGNORE NULLS
        OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date0 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as date_result
from dataset;
```